# Problem using SAP site

Tags: remote-desktop, compatibility, file-types

My father's company site uses SAP. He's trying to move to Linux (tired of Windows' bugs, problems and viruses) but he can't natively use the site's functionalities. When he tries to open those a popup appears asking whether he'd prefer to save or open filename.rdp.

What is this .rdp extension and how can we use those files?

Comment: .rdp files are used for (Windows) remote desktop sessions. They might contain specific Terminal Server Gateway details which can not be handled by Linux rdesktop and/or freerdp based tools. You can try do open a .rdp file using a text editor and use the information from that file to the corresponding arguments for rdesktop/freerdp.

Comment: I found out how to open rdp on remmina thanks to @Hesham Ahmed, still I need to open a VPN connection with the server I want to connect to. Should I use openvpn/pptp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention your Linux distro so I can't give you details on what steps to follow to get it on your machine, however most Linux distros have Remmina remote desktop client which can read RDP files. Just install Remmina and open the rdp file with it.

Comment: linux Mint. installed remmina, when I download the rdp file it doesn't show an "open with Remmina" option. after I download it, I don't know what to do

Comment: drag the rdp file into remmina

Comment: cannot import filename.rdp

Comment: Can you make sure you also install xfreerdp which is what remmina uses for RDP. **correction** remmina now uses remmina rdp plugin, make sure that is installed

Comment: can't find xfreerdp in the repo, I've got freerdp though

Comment: Please install remmina-plugin-rdp which is what remmina now uses for rdp

Comment: can now read rdp files, but still doesn't let me use remote apps (Excel, Word and a Logon feature)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: cannot establish a connection with the server

Comment: That could be due to a lot of reasons, can you make sure the remote server is reachable? (Try pinging it if you know the IP) You might need VPN connection to the corporate network. You can get the server name from remmina by clicking edit button and checking the server field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40941/discussion-between-oxen-eknat-and-hesham-ahmed).